# Locals not set when rendering multiple partials from the same controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This bug has me perplexed.

I am displaying a Widget with the last 5 data points and a form for a new data_point.  When I try to render both the form and the display partial it fails with a routing error.  If I comment out **either** partial it works fine.  So with only the form partial it works, or with only the display partial it works fine with the other.

Three relevant models/controllers: Widget, DataSet and DataPoint. DataPoints is STI so I have different partials to display the different types that match the class name.

When both `render :partial => ...` are uncommented it looks as if the data_point being passed to the second partial is the same as the data_point being passed to the first partial.  It is all nil with only a data_set_id.  I tried renaming the local from :data_point to :dp in case it was a name collision.

View, both partials and the routing error shown at the bottom.

Is there a limitation on passing :locals to partials when you are trying to render more than one partial in a view?

### View: show.html.haml (the show action on the controller is empty)

```
- title "#{@widget.type.underscore.humanize} for #{@widget.data_set.name.to_s.downcase}"

.row

  .span6
    = render :partial => 'data_points/form', :locals => { :data_set => @widget.data_set, :data_point => @widget.data_set.data_points.build }
    %br
    - last_5 = @widget.data_set.data_points.last(5)
    - if last_5.count > 0
      %h3= "Last #{pluralize( last_5.count, 'Entry' )}"
      - last_5.each do |dp|
        %pre
          = dp.inspect
        = render :partial => "data_points/#{@widget.data_set.data_type.underscore}", :locals => { :data_set => @widget.data_set, :data_point => dp }
    - else
      %h3 No data yet!

    = form_tag( push_widget_path @widget, :method => 'POST' ) do
      = submit_tag( "Push Data", :class=>"btn btn-primary" )
      = link_to "Edit your data", data_set_path( @widget.data_set ), :class=>'btn'

  .span6
    = image_tag "widgets/#{@widget.type.underscore}.png"
    %p
      Using the 
      %b= link_to @widget.data_set.name, @widget.data_set
      data set.

      = render :partial => "widgets/#{@widget[:type].underscore}", :locals => { :widget => @widget } rescue nil
    %p
      = link_to 'Edit', edit_widget_path(@widget), :class=>'btn'
```

## Form Partial (data_points/_form.html.haml)

```
%pre
  = data_set.inspect
%pre
  = data_point.inspect
= form_for [data_set,data_point], :html=>{:class => 'well form-horizontal'} do |f|
  -if data_point.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(data_point.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this data_point from being saved:"
      %ul
        - data_point.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg
  = render :partial => "data_points/#{data_set.data_type.underscore}_form", :locals => { :f => f, :data_point => data_point, :data_set => data_set }
  = f.text_field :created_at, :type=>'datetime'
  .form-actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```

## Display Partial (data_points/_multi_value_data_point.html.haml)

```
.data-point{ :id=>"data-point-#{data_point.id}"}
  %span.value 
    - data_point.data.map do |k,v|
      - label = data_set.properties[:data_series][k][:name]
      %span.key= "#{label}: "
      = v
  .meta
    = data_point.created_at 
    %span.edit
      = link_to 'Edit', edit_data_set_data_point_path( data_set, data_point )
    %span.delete
      = link_to 'Destroy', [data_set, data_point], :method => :delete, :data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}
    =# link_to 'Edit', '#', id: "edit-data-point-#{data_point.id}"
    :javascript
      $("#edit-data-point-#{data_point.id}").click( function(e) {
        $("#data-point-#{data_point.id}").html( "#{escape_javascript( render :partial => "data_points/multi_value_data_point_form", :locals => { data_set: data_set, data_point: data_point } )}");
        return false;
      });
```

## Routing Error

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"data_points", :data_set_id=>#<MultiValueDataSet id: 4, ... properties removed ... type: "MultiValueDataSet">, :id=>#<DataPoint id: nil, data: {}, data_set_id: 4, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

Comment: The reason this is failing is because of the edit link in the display partial and because the form builds a new data_point.  Turns out that even though the new datapoint is not saved to the database, last() will return it.  This new nil data_point breaks the edit link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that the form is building a new element that isn't saved, and last is returning that unsaved element.

Simple solution, replace .last(5) with .find( :all, order: 'id desc', limit: 5 )